# Keep one image in imageview stationary and scroll second image below first image

Tags: android, android-layout, android-intent

I have got two images one that i want to display on the top of the screen the second one at the bottom of the first image.  Now I want to scroll the second image (which is text) but not to scroll over the first image. So basically its a map at the top which i don't want to scroll and then the text at the bottom which i want to scroll. At the moment the first image is at the back and the second on top.  This is my code for xml.

```
<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/imageView1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:src="@drawable/farsouthroute"
    android:layout_marginTop="0dp"
    />


 <ScrollView 
   android:layout_width="fill_parent"
   android:layout_height="fill_parent">

   <RelativeLayout
       android:layout_width="fill_parent"
       android:layout_height="fill_parent">

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/imageView2"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:layout_below="@+id/imageView1"
    android:src="@drawable/routesouth"
    android:scaleType="fitCenter">


  </ImageView>
 </RelativeLayout>
 </ScrollView>


</RelativeLayout>
```

and here is the java.

```
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.pm.ActivityInfo;
import android.os.Handler; 
import android.view.Window;
import android.view.WindowManager;
import android.webkit.WebView; 

public class MainActivity extends Activity { 

private Handler mHandler = new Handler(); 

@Override 
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) { 
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE); 
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    }
}
```

What am i doing wrong here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One option could be to a LinearLayout instead of a RelativeLayout, with orientation set to vertical

```
<LinearLayout
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
>
    <ImageView
    android:id="@+id/imageView1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:src="@drawable/farsouthroute"
    android:layout_marginTop="0dp"
    />

<ScrollView 
 android:layout_width="fill_parent"
 android:layout_height="fill_parent">

    <ImageView
    android:id="@+id/imageView2"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:src="@drawable/routesouth"
    android:scaleType="fitCenter">
    </ImageView>

</ScrollView>


</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: Thanks it works, but now another problem arises,  I have now got a massive gap between the top image and the bottom image. On a tablet the bottom image is just in view, where on a smartphone can't see it.

Comment: Glad that it helped, please mark the answer as correct. Regarding the gap between the two images, you can change the android:layout_height to "wrap_content" instead of "fill_parent", for ScrollView & imageView2.

Comment: Thanks all is working now perfectly, but am using sliding drawer to select various routes, all work fine but once i selected a route the sliding drawer just disappears. (it works fine in reletavelayout) but now I have this in linearlayout. What can be the problem?

Comment: Hi sorry for the late reply.  I made a mistake with the code and only realized this morning.  Although i am now having issues in trying to load a .swf file in webview. (its a interactive map) but it doesn't seem to work, just gives me a blank screen on my tablet.  You jave been really helpfull thank you so much for that, but now im hoping you can help me with this?

Comment: I would recommend you mark this post as the correct answer so that anyone who stumbles upon would know what has worked for you. Also you can post your doubt as a new question and share the link with me, I will try and answer it.

Comment: I have posted the the qeustion and the link is  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13011193/how-can-i-get-to-display-a-interactive-map-in-webview  I have marked this question as correct.