# how can I display a interactive map in webview?

Tags: android, android-layout, android-intent

I am trying to display a interactive map that I have created with imapbuilder.  The problem is when i load it in my webview I just get a blank screen.  I have tried everything (am just wondering if my device can't handle flash have got sgs2 and Motorola xoom2 10.1in tablet with ICS on both).
Here is my code for XML.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"

android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
android:orientation="vertical" >



<WebView android:id="@+id/webview"

    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"/>



</LinearLayout>
```

For my .java;

```
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Handler; 
import android.view.Window;
import android.view.WindowManager;
import android.webkit.WebView; 

public class MainActivity extends Activity { 

  private Handler mHandler = new Handler(); 

  @Override 
  public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) { 
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE); 
    this.getWindow().setFlags   
    (WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN,
    WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN); 
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main); 
    WebView view=(WebView)findViewById(R.id.webview);
    view.getSettings().setPluginsEnabled(true);
    view.loadUrl("file:///android_asset/Interactive.htm"); 
    view.addJavascriptInterface(new MyJavaScriptInterface(), "Android"); 
} 

final class MyJavaScriptInterface 
{ 
    public void ProcessJavaScript(final String scriptname, final String args) 
        {              
            mHandler.post(new Runnable() 
                { 
                    public void run() 
                        { 
                            //Do your activities 
                        } 
                });
        }
}
}
```

In my assets folder is the Interactive.htm and sub folder with the flash files and stuff exported from the software I used.
So where am I going wrong?

Answer (score 0):

Did you add this permission to your manifest file?

`<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />`

Comment: Yes, and have added android:hardwareAccelerated="true" to the manifest aswell. In eclipse it works, but load it onto a device and I get a blank screen. And also view.getSettings().setPluginsEnabled(true); has got a line through it .setPluginsEnabled

Comment: No i dont use a simulator i work straight onto my sgs2 (debugmode) What I mean is if i double click on the Interactive.htm in assest folder it opens up and works, but not on my device.

Comment: Okay sorry, i didn't have flash player installed on my device. have installed it and it works now. thank for your help

Comment: But i cant seem to download it for my tablet.  can't find it anywhere on android market?